# SQL: highest order center for each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, with-statement

I'm very new to SQL (about two months into a learn-as-you-go position), and I am trying to write a query that will pull the main order center for each customer (i.e., which center is favored most by each customer). I only want one return per customer.

Right now, I have a query that returns the highest ordering customer and the associated center. It looks like this:

```
with x as (
select
row_number() over (order by cusid asc)
as row
,cusid
,centerid
,count(centerid) numofcenter
from orderdb
where isnumeric (cusid)=1
and estimate=0
group by centered, cusid
)
select row, centered, cusid, numofcenter
from x
where numofcenter=(
select max(numofcenter) from x)
order by cusid
```

Any help or guidance would be inexpressibly appreciated.

Comment: If you add the create table definition and a few inserts for example data you will get quick answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested, but this would be the basic concept I'd go for:

```
WITH cte_centers AS
(SELECT DISTINCT cusid FROM orderdb)
SELECT cte_centers.cusid, x.numofcenter
FROM cte_centers 
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 
    count(centerid) numofcenter
 FROM orderdb
 WHERE isnumeric (cusid)=1
    AND estimate=0
    AND orderdb.cusid = cte_centers.cusid
 GROUP BY centered, cusid
 ORDER BY count(centerid) DESC
)x
```

Comment: I had no idea about the cross apply function, but it's an awesome tool. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cusid ORDER BY COUNT(centerid) DESC) AS row,
        cusid,
        centerid,
        COUNT(centerid) numofcenter
    FROM
        orderdb
    WHERE
        ISNUMERIC(cusid) = 1
        AND estimate = 0
    GROUP BY
        cusid,
        centerid)
SELECT
    row,
    cusid,
    centerid,
    numofcenter
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    row = 1
```